# Is it possible to provide 'arguments' to Custom control Styles & Templates?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have 2 buttons, both of which are using a style to keep a consistent UI.  However for 1 button, I would like to provide an image for, and the other just text.

I suppose I could create a new style, copy everything over, and the reformat it to my liking, but this seems like waste, is time consuming, and i think i would have to do it for each instance I wish to have a image on a button.  I mean, that's fine, but I just want to know if there is an alternative that would make things more elegant.

I think I should somehow be able to push an 'arguement' or data to a style, either in or out of XAML to format the style, or something that would accomplish this (I'm sure the terminology is wrong).

Here is the Button Style:

```
<Style x:Key="Control_Button" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Image> <!-- Optional Image here --> </Image>
                    <TextBlock Name="btn" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Padding="16" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock.TextDecorations>
                            <TextDecoration Location="Underline" />
                        </TextBlock.TextDecorations>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <!-- FIX ME: not underlined normally -->

                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="TextBlock.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="btn" Property="TextDecorations" Value="none" />
                        <!-- FIX ME: underlined on hover -->
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not possible without creating a custom control or user control.

What you should do though is setting the contents of the button the way you like. If you want only a string, you can set it directly:

```
<Button>my text</Button>
```

or with a binding:

```
<Button Content={Binding textProperty} />
```

To include an image in the button, add a panel as content, in this example I added a `StackPanel`, but you can also use a `Grid` or any other element:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Content>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding myImagePath}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding myText}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Comment: I started to read more up on bindings, and i think your correct.  I think I have to have a viewmodel that'll control all the items.  It makes sense to do that anyway.  I'm going to let this one sit a few days, and since if no one offers up otherwise, I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: To use the code in this answer you dont have to have a viewmodel, I just included it with bindings because this is the way to go in WPF. If you want to set the image programmatically, you can give it a name and set its source property wherever you like.